# PyTorch preserving gradient using external libraries

Tags: scipy, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I have a GAN that returns a predicted `torch.tensor`. To guide this network, I have a loss function which is a summation of binary cross entropy loss (`BCELoss`) and Wasserstein distance. However, in order to calculate Wasserstein distance, I am using `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance` function from `SciPy` library. As you might know, this function requires two `NumPy` arrays as input. So, to use this function, I am converting my predicted tensor and ground-truth tensor to `NumPy` arrays as follows

```py
pred_np = pred_tensor.detach().cpu().clone().numpy().ravel()
target_np = target_tensor.detach().cpu().clone().numpy().ravel()

W_loss = wasserstein_distance(pred_np, target_np)
```

Then, total loss is obtained by adding `W_loss` to `BCELoss`. I am now showing this part because it is a bit unnecessary and not related to my question.

My concern is I am detaching gradient so I suppose that while optimizing and updating model parameters it will not consider `W_loss`. I am a bit newbie so I hope my question is clear and appreciate for answers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an object that is **not** a tensor that requires_grad to your loss is essentially adding a constant. The derivative of a constant is zero, so this added term is not doing anything to your network's weights.

tl;dr:
You need to rewrite the loss computation in pytorch (or just find an existing implementation, there's numerous on the internets).

Comment: What happens if I add `W_loss = torch.tensor(W_loss, requires_grad=True)`?

Comment: Nothing useful. Pytorch **cannot track gradients through non-tensor objects**. You would have a tensor that requires grad (fine and well) made of a numpy array that cant even track grad (woops). There is no backward computation that can go penetrate that numpy array, so no gradient will ever reach your model's parameters from there.